# Access RTDB from Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

For an existing app I save Users and Groups/Roles in RTDB.
For a new feature I want to use some of the advantages Firestore brings.

Is there a way to access RTDB directly out through Firestore Rules?

One way to achieve this, could be to set up a function to replicate my Users to Firestore. I can imagine I'm not the first to extend an existing app with Firestore. Is there any smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to access Firebase Realtime Database from your Firestore security rules. Allowing cross-product access would have too many performance implications.

Going forward I recommend [using custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to manage group membership in a more scalable way. Custom claims that you add to a profile are accessible in Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, *and* Cloud Storage security rules.

Comment: thank you, i totally forgot about that, I'm already using it for storage rules. :)